# Is it possible to catch Azure's DocumentClientException? Should I?

Tags: exception, azure-cosmosdb

I have old code that catches `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException` and reacts to it.
Then I updated some nuget dependencies and now `DocumentClientException` is `internal`.

The code I have catches `DocumentClientException` like so:

```
  ...
  // a-CosmosDb-call
  ...
catch (DocumentClientException de)
{
    if ((int)de.StatusCode != 429)
    {
        throw;
    }

    sleepTime = de.RetryAfter;
}
```

Is there a way to reuse the code above or have Microsoft changed the behaviour  of CosmodDb to not publish the reason for an error?

Comment: Have you updated the Nuget package for CosmosDB and now using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`? Check out `CosmosException` in that case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosexception?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: @GauravMantri Please write down your comment anser so I can honour you the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` Nuget package, you should use [`CosmosException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosexception?view=azure-dotnet). Your code would be something like:

```
  ...
  // a-CosmosDb-call
  ...
catch (CosmosException ce)
{
    if ((int)ce.StatusCode != 429)
    {
        throw;
    }

    sleepTime = ce.RetryAfter;
}
```